# HttpOnly still being set to false even after making changes to Apache config file and php.ini

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I have made the following attempts at trying to set `HttpOnly` to `true.

Attempt #1 - Add `ini_set` function

```
<?php 
ini_set( 'session.cookie_httponly', 1 );
session_start();
echo "hello";

setcookie("name", "Stevesy", time() + 3600);

?>
```

Attempt #2 - Add the following to httpd.conf file

```
<IfModule php5_module>
    php_flag session.cookie_httponly on
</IfModule>
```

Attempt #3 - Change `session.cookie_httponly` in php.ini to `true`

I have restarted the Apache web server.

[image]

Edit: I was able to change the HttpOnly of the cookie I set, name: Stevesy, to true. But PHPSESSION is still false.

Comment: Just the first method itself works fine on my machine. Can you try the same in incognito mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As /u/nice_dev suggested, it does work in incognito mode.

Edit: To be clear, attempts #1 and #3 both work fine. I didn't test #2.